# Jquery get IP Address on https

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, geolocation, ip-address

I've used ipinfo for getting IP Address and Location.

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    console.log(response.ip, response.country);
}, "jsonp");
```

My Website is using `https` Certificate.So, I'm getting `Unauthorized` error.

Is there any website having https certificate and gives out `IP Address`?

I've tried few websites but none of them have `https` certificate.